# Any idea how to enable multi filtering in this particular case ~ MixItUp plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am well aware that similar question exists on SO, but it was badly presented and remained unanswered because of that.

Here is the problem: I hit dead end on enabling multi-filtering on this plugin. Can anyone show me using the fiddle bellow how to do it?

Here is the catch: if I click lemons and click small, it should of course, display small lemons. But if I decide I want to have big lemons instead, it should switch and display only big lemons, while overriding previous "small" filter from the same filter category.

So, filters of the same category shouldn't stack on each other,but rather exclude each other without needing to "click them off" checkbox style. Is this even possible?

This is closest I got to achieving this effect, but the problem i described still persists

```
                targetSelector : '.mix',
                filterSelector : '.filter',
                sortSelector : '.sort',
                buttonEvent: 'click',
                effects : ['fade', 'scale'],
                listEffects : null,
                easing : 'smooth',
                layoutMode: 'grid',
                targetDisplayGrid : 'inline-block',
                targetDisplayList: 'block',
                listClass : '',
                gridClass : '',
                transitionSpeed : 600,
                showOnLoad : 'all',
                sortOnLoad : false,
                multiFilter : true,
                filterLogic : 'and',
                resizeContainer : true,
                minHeight : 0,
                failClass : 'fail',
                perspectiveDistance : '3000',
                perspectiveOrigin : '50% 50%',
                animateGridList : true,
                onMixLoad: null,
                onMixStart : null,
                onMixEnd : null,
```

Here is the fiddle, please help http://jsfiddle.net/DwX29/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the park-demo: http://mixitup.io/demos/parks

```
// HANDLE MULTI-DIMENSIONAL CHECKBOX FILTERING

            /*  
            *   The desired behaviour of multi-dimensional filtering can differ greatly 
            *   from project to project. MixItUp's built in filter button handlers are best
            *   suited to simple filter operations, so we will need to build our own handlers
            *   for this demo to achieve the precise behaviour we need.
            */

            var $filters = $('#Filters').find('li'),
                dimensions = {
                    region: 'all', // Create string for first dimension
                    recreation: 'all' // Create string for second dimension
                };

            // Bind checkbox click handlers:

            $filters.on('click',function(){
                var $t = $(this),
                    dimension = $t.attr('data-dimension'),
                    filter = $t.attr('data-filter'),
                    filterString = dimensions[dimension];

                if(filter == 'all'){
                    // If "all"
                    if(!$t.hasClass('active')){
                        // if unchecked, check "all" and uncheck all other active filters
                        $t.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                        // Replace entire string with "all"
                        filterString = 'all';   
                    } else {
                        // Uncheck
                        $t.removeClass('active');
                        // Emtpy string
                        filterString = '';
                    }
                } else {
                    // Else, uncheck "all"
                    $t.siblings('[data-filter="all"]').removeClass('active');
                    // Remove "all" from string
                    filterString = filterString.replace('all','');
                    if(!$t.hasClass('active')){
                        // Check checkbox
                        $t.addClass('active');
                        // Append filter to string
                        filterString = filterString == '' ? filter : filterString+' '+filter;
                    } else {
                        // Uncheck
                        $t.removeClass('active');
                        // Remove filter and preceeding space from string with RegEx
                        var re = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+filter);
                        filterString = filterString.replace(re,'');
                    };
                };

                // Set demension with filterString
                dimensions[dimension] = filterString;

                // We now have two strings containing the filter arguments for each dimension:  
                console.info('dimension 1: '+dimensions.region);
                console.info('dimension 2: '+dimensions.recreation);

                /*
                *   We then send these strings to MixItUp using the filter method. We can send as
                *   many dimensions to MixitUp as we need using an array as the second argument
                *   of the "filter" method. Each dimension must be a space seperated string.
                *
                *   In this case, MixItUp will show elements using OR logic within each dimension and
                *   AND logic between dimensions. At least one dimension must pass for the element to show.
                */

                $('#Parks').mixitup('filter',[dimensions.region, dimensions.recreation])            
            });
```